# How to run functions from Command Line in Node module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Lets say I have this node module in a file called runJS.js:

```
var someObject = {
    "getName": function(name){
        return name;
    }
}

exports.defult = someObject;
```

I know you can run the file at the command-line doing node runJS.js but how do say hey, I want to run getName from the command-line through the node command?

Comment: You would have to build that logic into your program, reading any passed in arguments and acting upon them.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js accepts a "-e" option

```
-e, --eval script     evaluate script
```

So you can try something like

```
node -e "require('./runJS').getName()"
```